# how can i align my tooltip exactly under my self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I need to align my custom tooltip exactly under this

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
```

can anyone help me to align my tooltip under navbar right button to show the info view for that button

Finding difficulties to set the x position of my tooltip view